# Filling in a VBScript array in a for loop

Tags: loops, vbscript

I'm attempting to create and fill in a two-dimensional array in VBScript, which resides in an ASP page. I have the following code:

```
Dim array(11, 6)

For record = 0 To 6
    array(6, record) = 8
    array(7, record) = "test"
Next

array(6, 3) = 8
array(7, 3) = "test"
```

The `for` loop doesn't work, though. Nothing gets filled in. If I do it explicitly, like the code after the loop, *that* works just fine.

I've hardly ever used VBScript before but this seems like it *should* work. Why is my loop not doing anything?

Comment: Don't you need to increment record in there somehwere? ;-)

Comment: That's what the FOR loop does, right?

Comment: It's a `for` loop; shouldn't that happen automatically? Even if not, the 0th element doesn't get filled in (and it doesn't loop forever).

Comment: Don't vbscript arrays start at 1?

Comment: @Alan - Actually, they don't, which surprised me.

Comment: Ah, shows you what I know about VBScript, huh? Sorry about that.  You guys are correct.

Comment: Tried this with a msgbox array(6,0) after the loop and it worked just fine... executed with "cscript test.vbs". Are you missing something?

Comment: You will need to "Redim Preserve".

Comment: @ghostdog74 - no, "Dim a(11,6)" creates a 12 x 7 FIXED array.

Comment: after the loop, add `if err.Number <> 0 then:  
 Response.Write err.description:  
 err.clear:  
end if`. this will give you an error message, if any. I think you may have a `option explicit` at the top of the script and the error is occurring because `record` is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "doesn't work" doesn't work. You'll have to describe exactly what you expect and what happens instead. Otherwise -

```
Dim a(11,6)
For i = 0 To 6
    a(6,i) = i
    a(7,i) = "test"
Next
WScript.Echo a(6,0),a(7,0)
WScript.Echo a(6,6),a(7,6)

0 test
6 test
```

Is there an evil "On Error Resume Next" active?

WRT the OERN:

You could insert an "On Error GoTo 0" immediately before the critical/new code and continue driving with your eyes shut with an "On Error Resume Next" immediately after it.

Or: copy the new code into a clean/empty .vbs to be used by cscript.exe

Or: post the relevant part of the code completely.

Comment: Yes, there is an `On Error Resume Next`. I can't really do a whole lot in the way of error checking because this is embedded in an ASP page (code which hasn't been touched in 10 years, too).

Comment: I used an `On Error GoTo 0` and received a "Variable is undefined" error. I shouldn't have to explicitly define each element in the array, right?

Comment: I would imagine that it's because `record` is not defined